# Building an arrays (not lists) based Hashtable in Python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, data-structures, hashtable

I have been trying to create a Hashtable data structure using only Python Arrays, not Python lists or Numpy Arrays, I know this can be done, but after much trial and error and searching the internet, I haven't found an answer that actually works.

[Python Arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

Thinking back to Datastructures, building a Hashtable can be done with Linkedlists and a node class for iterating (we have iterable and zip, but I have concerns with optimization regarding having to zip whenever we query).

I have made a somewhat functional Hashtable with Python Arrays, but it's ability to store information is very limited as each slice can't even hold 'lorem,ipsum'(example) encoded to byte array and it doesn't utilize a node class.

This involved an array of hashed indexed keys, upon calling the correct key, the index of the sister array is called that matches the current index in the hashed-key array.

While most functional operations of the Hashtable do indeed work, there isn't a conventional method of storing encoded/byte coded data that I can find or figure out.

Any hints and/or help is greatly appreciated!

````
from array import array

hashIndexes = array('q',[0])
hashValues = array('q',[0])
INIT_SIZE = 53 #prime init for buckets
hashValues = hashValues *INIT_SIZE
hashIndexes = hashIndexes *INIT_SIZE
hashTable = zip(hashIndexes,hashValues)

hashVal = 'clever key'


def salt(key,indexes=hashIndexes):
    '''Tested char array of 'clever key' returns 2015'''
    hashMultiple = 31
    sum = 0
    series = 0
    

    for x in key:
        ord(x)^sum + series + 1
        series+=1
        sum= sum + series
    salt = (sum + series) * hashMultiple
    if(salt in indexes==True):
        print("WARN: index already exists; fix in later version")
        pass
    
    return salt

def nuHash(hash, bucket_size=INIT_SIZE):
    '''Default value returns tested string at 1'''
    nuIndex = hash % bucket_size
    return nuIndex

def desalinate(key):
    '''Tested char array of 'clever key' returns 2015'''
    hashMultiple = 31
    sum = 0
    series = 0
    

    for x in key:
        ord(x)^sum + series + 1
        series+=1
        sum= sum + series
    salt = (sum + series) * hashMultiple
    if(salt in indexes==False):
        print("WARN: key not found")
        pass
    
    return salt

def addEntry(key,value,indexes=hashIndexes, values=hashValues):
    '''checks for hashed key'''
    loc = nuHash(salt(key))
    values[loc] = value
    pass

def getEntry(key,indexes=hashIndexes, values=hashValues):
    '''calls key to find value'''
    
    value = values[nuHash(desalinate(key))]
    print(key+" : "+str(value))
    return value```
````

Comment: Can we see your implementation? Most implementations I'm aware of don't store the value itself in the hash table, but instead store a pointer to the object. You could create a value store of some type (a list basically), and then store the offset of the value in your hashtable.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I just added my code to the original post; not yet optimized or very well thought-out outside of a few minutes of drawing it out.